# Read .CSV file in PHP as a table

Tags: php, file, csv

I am currently on a project where I need some information to be posted to a csv file and then read back so the previous information can be seen and then edited by the user. Kind of like a database table where the information will be in the cell it should be with some text next to that in another row.

At the minute my code has two tables, one showing the information from the csv and one which sends the data to the csv, but I want this to be merged so that they can see what the previously created information was and then they can edit this information click submit and that is the information which will the appear in the table.

Here is my code at the minute...

```
$myfile = "outputfile.csv"; 
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$f = fopen($myfile, 'r');
echo "<table>";
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
echo "
<form action='' method='POST'>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td><input name='var1' type='text'></td>
        <td>MMR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name='var2' type='text'></td>
        <td>FIVE_IN_ONE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name='var3' type='text'></td>
        <td>BOOSTER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name='var4' type='text'></td>
        <td>MENC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>";
} else {
    $text1 = $_POST['var1'];
    $text2 = $_POST['var2'];
    $text3 = $_POST['var3'];
    $text4 = $_POST['var4'];

    $fh = fopen($myfile, 'w+');
    fwrite($fh, $text1 . "\r\n" . $text2 . "\r\n" . $text3 . "\r\n" . $text4);
    fclose($fh);

    echo $text1 . "<br>" . $text2 . "<br>" . $text3 . "<br>" . $text4; 
}
```

Comment: ... and what is your question?

Comment: My question is, how do I make the each new line in the CSV file go onto a new line of the table with the MMR, BOOSTER etc being on the right hand side of the the loop. I don't want two seperate table, I want the tables to be merged together. And I want it so you can delete and/or edit the information seen. Sorry, but I'm rubbish at explaining something even though I have it pictured in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has csv functionality built in:

```
$arrayOfValues = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('myfile.csv'));
foreach($arrayOfValues as $row)
{
  foreach($row as $col)
  {
    echo $col . '&nbsp;';
  }
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that. But I would like my MMR, BOOSTER on the right side of one table to be merged with the table shown and have it so you can edit the text shown from the csv file...

Comment: So merge all of your data into the same array, then rewrite the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

As David said, use str_getcsv. To put everything in place so that people can live-edit, you want to display the form like this:

```
$arrayOfValues = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('myfile.csv'));
foreach($arrayOfValues as $row)
{
  $index=0;
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($row as $col)
  {
     echo "<td><input name='var".$index."' type='text' value='".$col."'></td>";
     $index++;
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: actually, you'd want to give the variables uniquer names, e.g. var_x_y, so that you can just loop through the names, from var_0_0 until var_m_n.

Comment: Thank you, you and Dave have helped a lot.